# Como resolver esse erro de session o_rdwr?

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso resolver esse 
`php session failed o_rdwr no such file or directory`

O erro ocorre quando faço login no servidor, porém, localmente ele não dá erro nenhum e loga normalmente alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atribua permissões de escrita para o path especificado em session.

Em ambiente Linux/Unix, permissão 0777.

Caso não tenha acesso ao diretório, configure um caminho próprio para um local onde você tenha acesso para alterar as permissões da pasta.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.save_path','/aqui/caminho/completo/onde/as/sessoes/serão/salvas/');

session_start();
?>
```

Também pode usar a função session_save_path()

```
<?php       
session_save_path('/aqui/caminho/completo/onde/as/sessoes/serão/salvas/');

session_start();
?>
```

A permissão não precisa ser necessariamente 0777. Basta apenas setar um valor que permita leitura e escrita. No entanto, para não complicar muito, apenas configure como 0777.